# Need redirecting output from multi-threaded socket server to other clients.

Tags: java, sockets, system.out

What I have is a multi threaded socket server listening for clients. New thread is created and started for opened connections. Clients can ask a server to execute some commands via Runtime .exec() method. Any new command received is handled by new thread (with PrintWriter passed as a parameter) and all the output (std/err) is send over the socket with PrintWriter.

The problem is that when the command takes longer (i.e. daemon) and the client disconnects for any reason I can't get the output anymore. I need to find a way of getting the output from that command execution thread on another connection (new client session which will be on another thread).

I could try to send all the output from commands to System.out and try to send it (System.out) over socket with PrintWriter (I don't know how to do this). And if I'm sucessfull maybe there is a way of sending all the such an output to every connected clients.

But then, I'm saving all the output to the database and in case of multiple clients connected I would end up having multiple inputs in my database.

Please give me some ideas as how I could go about with this issue. Thanks

Comment: I think that creating another server to just listen and store output from the former multi threaded server could do the trick. When there's no connection storing output temporarily in file and re transmit everything after re connection. This way I don't lose any output and still can use many clients to issue commands. Client only displays output from their connections doesn't have to store it in db (to avoid duplicate entries).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make your calls asynchronous. Executing tasks of unknown duration should never be made synchronously.

I would consider using a "reactor"-type server (i.e.: one thread per client = quick death) and using some type of message passing mechanism for long running transactions. There are a lot of middlewares that do this kind of work, it really depends on what platform you're on.

By the way, using a socket connection to execute command on a remote machine is a security flaw, but you probably already know that!

Comment: Each command is executed in new thread, for short executions the thread ends quickly. The long lasting commands still executes, even when the connection is broken (no output sent though). Normally I'd go for ActiveMQ or similar, but here I want to make it strictly socket based (direct), maybe with temporary hashed file storage). Despite the security flaws.

Comment: Well, if you can't/don't want to use any middleware, you have to write one yourself. You have to consider a use case where the flows is asynchronous, and think about the best way to get the result back, as the temporary store you suggested. This is anyway a more costly solution than using a full-blown async task execution system. The service architecture should not be tightly related to the technology used to publish the service itself. e.g.: if your system handles async tasks, the possibility to call them synchronously via socket should only be an option.

Answer (score 0):

So, did you consider using a session ID for each connection? This ID will be associated with the output of each execution. So the same output could be retrieved on a subsequent call from the same user. Temporarily, the output could be stored at a repository (e.g. DB, memory, file).

Please correct me if I am not getting your question properly.

Comment: I don't need session ID's and I can't think of good benefit of them in my case. What I need is some way of redirecting all the output (regardless of which client initiated it) to currently connected client (ideally only one). Let's say I had previously connected clients which had started couple of daemons on the server machine, I need to have some command on client (e.g. "getAllOutput") to redirect all the output from the server to that client.   When I make new connection, I'd like to have option to get all the servers output to this connected client.

Comment: temporarily storing the output when there's no connected client getting the output is a good idea though

Comment: Also when I decide to disconnect that temporary client I'd like to send the output back to the client previously connected (given the connection is still up).

Comment: I see your point. In your case I would choose fire-and-forget web service for the invoking the execution. Then, I would save the output at a repository (temporarily). And finally, there would be a second (synchronous) web service to get the output. Is this fitting your needs?

Comment: I know I want to much. Probably I need to think everything again and design the system differently from scratch. Any tips.